# Languages in Nexus 4 from Germany

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-4, languages

I hope my question is not too strange. I would like to buy the current Google Nexus 4 16GB in Germany from Google Play. But I am interested if anyone can confirm that it has English language installed in in the system languages. I am concerned that it only has German.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will indeed have English. The default language may be German, but it can be changed in the settings.